# WSO2 Identity Server: How to handle SAML2 SSO Logout request

Tags: thingworx, wso2-identity-server

I am using Identity Server for SSO in Thingworx. I am able to federate login, however I am not able to handle Logout.

Pls assist on how to handle logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify IDP logout URL from the Saml Federated IDP configuration.

[image]

Thanks
Isura

Comment: if it is IdP logout url, considering relative url with value "logout/single"  is entered there in the box. What info should request carry, and exactly what API to hit.

Comment: Refer this blog for IdP initiated logout - http://daytodayjava.blogspot.com/2015/08/saml2-idp-initiated-single-logout-with.html

Comment: This works thanks. However, my IS is running on EC2 and sending slo to https://ec2-52-XXXXX.amazonaws.com:9443/samlsso?slo=true after logout the page redirects to https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do . I was expecting it should be https://<IS_Server>:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do . Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216067/wso2-identity-server-slo-redirect-not-working-as-expected/40231337#40231337