# WSO2 Identity Server: SLO redirect not working as expected

Tags: wso2-identity-server

My IS is running on EC2 and sending slo to `https://ec2-52-XXXXX.amazonaws.com:9443/samlsso?slo=true` after logout the page redirects to `localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do` . I was expecting it should be `https://<IS_Server>:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logo‌​ut.do` . Any idea what I am missing?  How/Where to specify and change the urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the host name at carbon.xml. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198029/2751640) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SLO URL in management console. Goto - Add **service Provider** > **Inbound Authentication Configuration** >**SAML SSOconfiguration**.

You need to tick tick the **enable single logout** and past the **SLO URL** in relevant box.

For more details, 
[IS 5.1.0 here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) 
[IS 5.0.0 here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0)

Comment: Hi @pradeepa, that setup is existing. Enable Single Logout (checked), SLO Response URL (https://ec2-xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do?spEntityID=Thingworx), same value for SLO Request URL. However on hitting logout url https://ec2-52-XXXXX.amazonaws.com:9443/samlsso?slo=true, it redirecting to https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do?spEntityID=Thingworx